# Rx multiple asynchronous operations

Tags: c#, asynchronous, system.reactive

I am reading about Rx and going through some examples. I am trying to implement this:

```
List<A> LIstA {get;set;}
List<B> LIstB {get;set;}
List<C> LIstC {get;set;}

private void GetItems()
{
    ListA = GetItemsA();
    ListB = GetItemsB();
    ListC = GetItemsC();
}
```

All this code is executed on main thread. I removed the code where main thread (UI) consumes this lists. What I would like is to fetch those items in asynchronous matter, but I need results coming in predefined sequence.

Running it in asynchronous manner is no trouble, but I am having a problem getting results in predefined sequence. So, I run the code, UI is displayed, after a few seconds `ListA` gets populated, then `ListB`, and finally `ListC`, only in this predefined sequence.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Task` or `async` might be a better fit for this model than Rx.

Nonetheless, from what I can infer for your question, use concat to connect an observable after the previous one completes:

```
        Func<Action, IObservable<Unit>> fetch = 
            action => Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Start(action));

        fetch(() => A())
        .Concat(fetch(() => B()))
        .Concat(fetch(() => C()))
        .Subscribe();
```

Comment: Hi Asti, I already have it implemented with Task. I needed to use coroutines in this case, and this kind of complicated some other stuff (overriding in descendant classes). If you know of example using Task, without using coroutines, please let me know. As for your example using Rx, what exactly is Unit? Is it base class for types A, B and C? And what is action? Its not quite clear from the code you have posted.

Comment: [Unit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.unit(v=vs.103).aspx) is the equivalent of `void` in functional programming. It can be considered as the result of executing a method which returns nothing. The first line is a delegate to avoid repetition. You can replace `() => A()` with `() => ListA = GetItemsA()` as per your example.

Comment: So, now I am able to compile, and data is retrieved asynchronously and in predefined sequence - that works OK. Problem: I cannot use LIstA and ListB on UI (main thread), receiving: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.". I have tried adding .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current) before the .Subscribe(), but it didn't help. How to get the result lists back on the main thread?

Comment: @Goran I didn't know your action was causing an actual view update. You could try splitting the GetItem methods and the assigning method into two. 
`Observable.Start(GetItems).Do(AssignValue, DispatcherScheduler.Instance)`

Answer (score 0):

Do this work for you?

```
GetItemsA().ToObservable()
    .Zip(GetItemsB().ToObservable(), (a, b) => new { a, b, })
    .Zip(GetItemsC().ToObservable(), (ab, c) => new { ab.a, ab.b, c, })
    .Subscribe(abc =>
    {
        ListA = abc.a;
        ListB = abc.b;
        ListC = abc.c;
    });
```

Comment: This makes sure that all three things are executed before Subscribe is called, but this doesn't execute them sequentially like the OP asked

Comment: @PaulBetts - Ah, I thought the assignment had to be sequential.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question you have three collections of different types. Obviously one cannot concatonate three streams of different types. I think @Enigmativity's is allmost correct but in order for it to work you need change it to:

```
var uiScheduler = new SynchronizationContextScheduler(SynchronizationContext.Current);
ListA = new ListA();
ListB = new ListB();
ListC = new ListC();

GetItemsA().ToObservable()
.Zip(GetItemsB().ToObservable(), (a, b) => new { a, b, })
.Zip(GetItemsC().ToObservable(), (ab, c) => new { ab.a, ab.b, c, })
.ObserveOn(uiScheduler)
.Subscribe(abc =>
{
    ListA.Add(abc.a);
    ListB.Add(abc.b);
    ListC.Add(abc.c);
});
```

Another solution might be:

```
var a = Observable.Start(() => GetListA());
var b = Observable.Start(() => GetListB());
var c = Observable.Start(() => GetListC());

a.Zip(b, c, (x, y, z) => Tuple.Create(x, y, z))
    .ObserveOn(uiScheduler)
    .Subscribe(result =>
                 {
                   ListA = result.Item1;
                   ListB = result.Item2;
                   ListC = result.Item3;
                 });
```

I you want the collections as soon as they are created:

```
  a.ObserveOn(uiScheduler)
    .Do(l => ListA = l)
    .Zip(b, (la, lb) => lb)
    .ObserveOn(uiScheduler)
    .Do(l => ListB = l)
    .Zip(c, (lb, lc) => lc)
    .ObserveOn(uiScheduler)
    .Subscribe(listc => ListC = listc);
```

Comment: This the problem with this is that a, b, and c evaluate simultaneously. From OPs question: "I need results coming in predefined sequence."

Answer (score 0):

You could use dynamics as well ...:

```
void Main()
{
    var q =
    from @as in Observable.Start(() => GetItemsA())
    from bs in Observable.Start(() => GetItemsB())
    from cs in Observable.Start(() => GetItemsC())
    select @as.Cast<dynamic>().Concat(bs.Cast<dynamic>()).Concat(cs.Cast<dynamic>());   
    q.Subscribe(t => t.Dump()); 
}

// Define other methods and classes here
private IEnumerable<int> GetItemsA() {
    yield return 1;
    Thread.Sleep(500);
    yield return 2;
    yield return 3;
}
private IEnumerable<string> GetItemsB() {
    yield return "A";
    yield return "B";
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    yield return "C";
}
private List<float> GetItemsC() {
    return new List<float> { 1.1f, 2.2f, 3.3f };
}
```